# ActiveAdmin form for has_many relationship won't let you create because the parent does not exist

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I have **Table1** who has a has_many relationship with **Table2**

```
# app/models/table1.rb
class Table1 < ApplicationRecord
     .
     .
     .
  has_many :table2_relations, class_name: Table2, foreign_key: instance2_id
```

The belongs_to relationship in Table2 is marked as required:

```
# app/models/table2.rb
class Table2 < ApplicationRecord
     .
     .
     .
  belongs_to instance2, class_name: Table1, required: true
```

My ActiveAdmin file is :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Table1 do
  .
  .
  .
  controller do
    def create
       .
       .
       .
    end
```

I have an ActiveAdmin page to create a new Table1 that also include table2_relations but since belongs_to required is true, when super is called, it will do all insert statements first then commit, causing a instance2 does not exist error because the creation of Table1 has not commited yet before creation of table2_relations is committed. The creation of table2_relations is only possible in the context of updating. How can I make the creation of Table1 committed first before creation of table2_relations? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing Nested Resources just like what Pragya said, but it won't work. then I find out that I have to add inverse_of: :instance2 in Table1 just like this answer: [ActiveAdmin has_many form not saved if parent model is new and is NOT NULL in child model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851203/activeadmin-has-many-form-not-saved-if-parent-model-is-new-and-is-not-null-in-ch/29866755#29866755)

Answer (score 0):

See the heading 'Nested Resources' on the below link:

Link: https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html

Try to create nested form. This will solve the problem.